# D3 graph continues to display even after navigating away from the template that rendered it

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, meteor

I am creating a graph editor on meteor using the D3 engine. I render the template that consists of the graph editor only on one specific route. However, once I create my graph on that route (page), the same graph appears on all other pages. So even after I navigate away from the graph editing page to a different page (route) that renders a completely different template, the graph I created on the graph editor template is still appearing on the page. I am not sure as to why this is happening, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Code? Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely bound your svg element to the page body.

In this case, it makes more sense to create a container element such as

`<div class=container></div>`

and then use `d3.select(div.container).append("svg")` to append your svg.

Comment: That makes sense. I was binding the svg element to the page body. However, I've used a container element now, but that does not seem to fix the problem. Any idea why?

Comment: It's hard to tell much more without seeing any code/html. My main advice would be to check all of your select/selectAll statements carefully, and make sure that container element is being hidden properly when you navigate away from that page.